# Error 'svn' executable not found for subrepo '<folder name>'

Tags: svn, mercurial

It is established:
TortoiseSVN 1.7.6 (64-bit);
TortoiseHg 2.3.2 (64-bit);

The project contains a folder that is hosted in SVN.
Cloning a Mercurial - error 'svn' executable not found for subrepo '[folder name]'

Access to the SVN repository there. Password to access saved.
TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHg are registered in the PATH.

Can you please tell how to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**
The problem is solved.

Solution:
1) Dial in cmd command "svn".

2) If the error appears:
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
That must be reinstalled when you install TortoiseSVN and mark the item "Command line client tools"
Or separately to install Subversion Command-Line Client
Thank you all for your comments

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, or accept Xenon's answer (which is a copy of your answer)

Comment: @JimSchubert I have deleted my answer and instead submitted an edit to the question improving the solution formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved.

Solution:
1) Dial in cmd command "svn".

2) If the error appears:

'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

That must be reinstalled when you install TortoiseSVN and mark the item "Command line client tools"
Or separately to install Subversion Command-Line Client
Thank you all for your comments

Comment: The operation will be available within a few hours